# SQLite rawQuery not returning any result with integer parameter

Tags: android, sqlite

The following rawQuery on SQLite database in Android returns no results:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " +
    "(SELECT MATCH_ID, PLAYER_ID, SUM(SHOTS) AS SHOT_SUM, SUM(MAX(GOAL - SHOTS + 2, 0)) AS SCORE_SUM, COUNT(SHOTS) AS SHOT_COUNT " +
        "FROM RESULT R INNER JOIN MATCH M ON M.ID = R.MATCH_ID " +
        "INNER JOIN PLAYER P ON R.PLAYER_ID = P.ID " +
            "WHERE R.IS_ACTIVE=1 AND SHOTS>0 AND P.IS_ACTIVE=1 AND NOT_COMPLETE=0 " +
            "GROUP BY MATCH_ID, PLAYER_ID) " +
    "WHERE SHOT_COUNT=? ORDER BY SHOT_SUM;";

Cursor cursor = this.db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { String.valueOf(9) });
```

When I replace the parameter in the where clause by a hardcoded value it works like expected:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " +
    "(SELECT MATCH_ID, PLAYER_ID, SUM(SHOTS) AS SHOT_SUM, SUM(MAX(GOAL - SHOTS + 2, 0)) AS SCORE_SUM, COUNT(SHOTS) AS SHOT_COUNT " +
        "FROM RESULT R INNER JOIN MATCH M ON M.ID = R.MATCH_ID " +
        "INNER JOIN PLAYER P ON R.PLAYER_ID = P.ID " +
            "WHERE R.IS_ACTIVE=1 AND SHOTS>0 AND P.IS_ACTIVE=1 AND NOT_COMPLETE=0 " +
            "GROUP BY MATCH_ID, PLAYER_ID) " +
    "WHERE SHOT_COUNT=9 ORDER BY SHOT_SUM;";

Cursor cursor = this.db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because SHOT_COUNT is a computed column, it doesn't match the string value you pass as a parameter. Replace this:

```
COUNT(SHOTS) AS SHOT_COUNT
```

with this:

```
CAST(COUNT(SHOTS) AS TEXT) AS SHOT_COUNT
```